# DataProvider is not allowing to return String 2D array

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng-dataprovider

I have created a Selenium framework with TestNG. In this framework, the @Dataprovider contains set of code that reads data from an Excel and returns this value as a 2D array to @Test.

```
@DataProvider(name="excelParam")
    public static String[][] loginData()
    {
        return Util.Excel.get("/LearningSelenium/creds.xls");
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "excelParam")
    public void loginTest(String username, String password) {
        driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
}
```

The 'get' method returns String[][]. But I am getting error as "DataProvider must return Object[][]". If I change it to Object[][], then my test case is failing with below error:

```
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
[public void ParameterTestExcel.loginTest(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)] has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level annotation).
Data provider mismatch

Test ignored.

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 **

    @DataProvider(name ="Testlogin")
        public Object[][]  getData()
        {
            // here you can give data
            return data;
        }

**

your code like " public static String[][] loginData()
    {
        return Util.Excel.get("/LearningSelenium/creds.xls");
    }

your return type is string but that should be Object[][]
```